# np.kron() in Python and MATLAB

Tags: python, arrays, matlab

I am working on translating some Matlab code to Python. I am stuck on the following lines:

Matlab code (note: `mgrid` is a 35x1 vector; `pgrid` is a 1000x1 vector):

```matlab
grid_val = zeros(35000,2);

grid_val(:,1) = kron(ones(35,1),pgrid);
grid_val(:,2) = kron(mgrid,ones(1000,1));
```

My problem is that `kron(ones(35,1),pgrid)` is a 35x1000 array while `kron(mgrid,ones(1000,1))` is a 1000x35 array. How do I insert those to the first and secon column of `grid_val` as what Matlab code did?

Comment: MATLAB flattens the array on assignment like this. I think `np.ravel` does this in Python.

Comment: also noticed that numpy is row major, when matlab is column major, it can lead to some error when translating a code.